# Casecade DropDownList w/ Ajax Binding to Model

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Looking for some help on binding the AJAX value(members_exams_proctorname) into the model so it will save during post.  The school drop down work and will get the values of the proctor name.  When I inspect element I can see the name of the proctors.

[image: Inspect Element]

Model

```
    public int members_exams_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> members_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> schools_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> exams_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> members_exams_status_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> members_exams_types_id { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_username { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_password { get; set; }
     public string members_exams_firstname { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_middlename { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_lastname { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_ssn { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> members_exams_expirationdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> members_exams_examdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> members_exams_session { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> members_exams_passingscore { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> members_exams_score { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> members_exams_startdate { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_address { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_city { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_state { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_zip { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_phone { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_testinglocation { get; set; }
    public string members_exams_proctorname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> members_exams_application { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> members_exams_payment { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> members_exams_diploma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> members_exams_processing { get; set; }
```

Controllers

```
   public ActionResult NewTryDDL()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> schoolsId = new List<SelectListItem>();
        members_exams members_exams = new members_exams();

        List<school> sch = db.schools.ToList();
        sch.ForEach(x =>
        {
            schoolsId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_name, Value = x.schools_id.ToString() });
        });
        ;
        ViewBag.schools_id = schoolsId;
        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description");
        return View(members_exams);
    }

            [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetContact(string schools_id)
    {
        int schoolId;
        List<SelectListItem> members_exams_proctorname = new List<SelectListItem>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(schools_id))
        {
            schoolId = Convert.ToInt32(schools_id);
            List<schools_contacts> contact = db.schools_contacts.Where(x => x.schools_id == schoolId).ToList();
            contact.ForEach(x =>
            {
                members_exams_proctorname.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_contacts_firstname, Value = x.schools_contacts_firstname.ToString() });
            });
        }
        return Json(members_exams_proctorname, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult NewTryDDL([Bind(Include = "members_exams_id,members_id,schools_id,exams_id,members_exams_status_id,members_exams_types_id,members_exams_username,members_exams_password,members_exams_firstname,members_exams_middlename,members_exams_lastname,members_exams_ssn,members_exams_email,members_exams_expirationdate,members_exams_examdate,members_exams_session,members_exams_passingscore,members_exams_score,members_exams_startdate,members_exams_address,members_exams_city,members_exams_state,members_exams_zip,members_exams_phone,members_exams_testinglocation,members_exams_proctorname,members_exams_application,members_exams_payment,members_exams_diploma,members_exams_processing")] members_exams members_exams)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.members_exams.Add(members_exams);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        List<SelectListItem> schoolsId = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<school> sch = db.schools.ToList();
        sch.ForEach(x =>
        {
            schoolsId.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.schools_name, Value = x.schools_id.ToString() });
        });
        ;
        ViewBag.schools_id = schoolsId;

        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description", members_exams.exams_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description", members_exams.members_exams_types_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description", members_exams.members_exams_status_id);

        return View(members_exams);
    }
```

Index

```
      <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.schools_id, "schools_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownList("schools_id", null, "---Select School---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlSchool" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.schools_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, "Proctor Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div id="Name" class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.members_exams_proctorname, new List<SelectListItem>(), "---Select Name---", new { @id = "ddlName" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The original Index

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will work if I type in the proctor name but I am looking for the cascade dropdown that will save DB and bind to the model.  I have tried to rework this for a few days but keep getting stuck on "Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details".  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym). And get rid of all that use of `ViewBag` and use a view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CreateForSchool(int? id, string name, string mname, string lname, string ssn, string email, string address, string city, string state, string zip, string phone, string username, DateTime expirationDate, short? schools_id, string members_exams_proctorname, string members_exams_testinglocation) 
{
        members_exams members_exams = new members_exams();

        string randoms = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("+", string.Empty).Substring(0, 4).ToUpper();

        members_exams.members_id = id;
        members_exams.members_exams_firstname = name;
        members_exams.members_exams_middlename = mname;
        members_exams.members_exams_lastname = lname;
        members_exams.members_exams_ssn = ssn;
        members_exams.members_exams_email = email;
        members_exams.members_exams_address = address;
        members_exams.members_exams_city = city;
        members_exams.members_exams_state = state;
        members_exams.members_exams_zip = zip;
        members_exams.members_exams_phone = phone;
        members_exams.members_exams_expirationdate = expirationDate;
        members_exams.members_exams_username = name.Substring(0, Math.Min(name.Length, 1)) + lname.Substring(0, Math.Min(lname.Length, 3)) + ssn.Substring(5, Math.Min(ssn.Length, 4)) + randoms;
        members_exams.schools_id = schools_id;
        members_exams.members_exams_proctorname = members_exams_proctorname;
        members_exams.members_exams_testinglocation = members_exams_testinglocation;


        var exam = (from x in db.members_exams
                    join y in db.schools_contacts on x.schools_id equals y.schools_id
                    join z in db.schools on x.schools_id equals z.schools_id
                    where x.schools_id == schools_id
                    select x).ToList();

        ViewBag.SchoolName = new SelectList(db.schools.Where(x => x.schools_active == true).OrderBy(x => x.schools_name), "schools_id", "schools_name");


        ViewBag.Proctor = new SelectList(from x in exam.ToList()
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             members_exams_proctorname = x.members_exams_proctorname
                                         }, "schools_contacts_firstname", "schools_contacts_firstname");



        ViewBag.Location = new SelectList(from x in exam.ToList()
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              embers_exams_testinglocation = x.members_exams_testinglocation
                                          }, "schools_id", "schools_name");

        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description");
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description");           
        return View(members_exams);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

    public ActionResult CreateForSchool([Bind(Include = "members_exams_id,members_id,schools_id,exams_id,members_exams_status_id,members_exams_types_id,members_exams_username,members_exams_password,members_exams_firstname,members_exams_middlename,members_exams_lastname,members_exams_ssn,members_exams_email,members_exams_expirationdate,members_exams_examdate,members_exams_session,members_exams_passingscore,members_exams_score,members_exams_startdate,members_exams_address,members_exams_city,members_exams_state,members_exams_zip,members_exams_phone,members_exams_testinglocation,members_exams_proctorname,members_exams_application,members_exams_payment,members_exams_diploma,members_exams_processing")] members_exams members_exams)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.members_exams.Add(members_exams);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CreateForSchool", "Members");
        }


        ViewBag.members_exams_proctorname = new SelectList((from s in db.schools_contacts.OrderBy(s => s.school.schools_name).ToList()
                                                            select new
                                                            {
                                                                schools_contacts_id = s.schools_contacts_id,
                                                                FullString = s.school.schools_name + " " + s.schools_contacts_firstname + " " + s.schools_contacts_lastname
                                                            }),
                                                                    "schools_contacts_id",
                                                                    "FullString",
                                                                    null);

        ViewBag.exams_id = new SelectList(db.exams, "exams_id", "exams_description", members_exams.exams_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_status_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_status, "members_exams_status_id", "members_exams_status_description", members_exams.members_exams_status_id);
        ViewBag.members_exams_types_id = new SelectList(db.members_exams_types, "members_exams_types_id", "members_exams_types_description", members_exams.members_exams_types_id);
        ViewBag.schools_id = new SelectList(db.schools.Where(x => x.schools_active == true).OrderBy(s => s.schools_name), "schools_id", "schools_name");
        return View(members_exams);
    }
```

View

```
      <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.schools_id, "School", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.schools_id, ViewBag.SchoolName as SelectList, "--- Select School ---", new { @class = "form-control", id = "SchID" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.schools_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, "Proctor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.members_exams_proctorname, ViewBag.Proctor as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Proctor" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members_exams_proctorname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.members_exams_testinglocation, "Exam Location", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.members_exams_testinglocation, ViewBag.Location as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Location" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.members_exams_testinglocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


    <script>
$(function () {
    $("#SchID").change(function () {
        $.get("http://localhost/NAHPapp/members_exams/GetProctorbyId", { schools_id: $("#SchID").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#Proctor").empty();
            $.each(data,
                function (index, row) {
                    $("#Proctor").append(" <option value=' " + row.schools_contacts_firstname + ' ' + row.schools_contacts_lastname + " '>" + row.schools_contacts_firstname + ' ' + row.schools_contacts_lastname + " </option> ")
                });
        })
    });



    $("#SchID").change(function () {
        $.get("http://localhost/NAHPapp/members_exams/GetSchoolLocation", { schools_id: $("#SchID").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#Location").empty();
            $.each(data,
                function (index, row) {
                    $("#Location").append(" <option value=' " + row.schools_name + " '>" + row.schools_name + " </option> ")
                });
        })
    });

});
```